# Change the main width of Twenty Thirteen theme

Tags: themes, theme-twenty-thirteen

I would like to reduce the main width (including the header) of my Twenty Thirteen website, and change the color of the outside (in sort, something similar to the Twenty Twelve theme: https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwelve).

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your custom css, with 960px being your desired width.

```
.site {
  max-width: 960px;
}
```

And for the background color:

```
.body {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
```